# PHP CLI Connecting to WebSerbvice

Tags: php, linux, bash, web-services, soap

I am having an issue with running my PHP application from the command line.
I recently created a new Google Cloud Engine CentOS instance to host my PHP application.
This application has been running away fine on a different RHEL box.

The application is kicked off from a PHP script using a command similar to...

```
$command = 'bash -c "exec nohup setsid runPHPScript > /dev/null 2>&1 &"';
exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
```

`runPHPSCript` is a linux script that essentially runs the actual PHP command...

```
php myScript.php
```

`myScript.php` then goes off and connects to various webservices etc...

When I try to run this on my new instance (bearing in mind this all worked fine on my RHEL box) I get the following SOAP error...

```
(faultcode: HTTP, faultstring: Could not connect to host)
```

The SOAP setup/connection to the endPoint WSDL is actually successful but as soon as I try to send the request I get the error above.

I've been debugging this and reading up a bit and can confirm the following...

- HTTP & HTTPS are both enabled on the GCE instance.
- I have verified that both PHP & Apache are using the same php.ini (more on this below)
- I have checked both configurations using phpinfo() and php -i and can see the various SSL entries in the data

The strange part is that if I open `myScript.php` in a browser (its a LAMP stack) it connects fine to the webservice and I can see the valid response. This lead me to think the problem was different php.ini's being used.
Also, at the command prompt, if I just run `myScript.php` directly it also works fine...

```
php 'myScript.php'
```

returns a valid response too.

So the problem only seems to occur when I try to kick off the application using BASH.
Anyone got any ideas?

Robert

Comment: just curious...why cant you just do an `exec("php myScript.php");` in your code direcctly?

Comment: or just include('myScript.php')

Comment: @raidenance, honestly I can't remember why. This piece of code was written about 6 or 7 years ago. At the time I needed to be able to kick off a process that would run in the background and would not be tied to Apache or cause the parent script to hang while the forked script ran. I think I picked this method up on a website back then. Not sure if it was a limitation of PHP at the time but I see now that you can use exec to run processes in the background. Might try it.

Comment: Also, the linux script 'runPHPScript' doesn't just kick off the PHP script. There is other logic in there too. For example, it may kick off a number of instances of 'myScript.php'. This was essentially to try and have multiple 'threads' running

Comment: @dvm. just including it isn't an option based on my two comments above. Its done this way so that it runs off a linux process in the background and separate to Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up.
As per Raidenace suggestion, just running exec directly worked fine too...

"just curious...why cant you just do an exec("php myScript.php"); in your code direcctly?"